# PHP class initiation error?

Tags: php

I have

```
$test = 'SomeClass';
$ins = new $test;
```

I want to be able to catch the error if the name for `$test` doesn't exist.

I'm not sure what type of exception it threw as PHP didn't gave me anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

Check first like this:

```
if(class_exists($test)){
    $ins = new $test;
}else{
    die("Could not load class'" . $test ."'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a construction won't let you catch any errors unless you use some [error handler](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). However you can check whether class exists or not using [`class_exists()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

PS. You should use [reflection](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) as it is much more  verbose and clear. Also it uses exceptions so you can do something like:

```
try {
    $ref = new \ReflectionClass($className);
} catch (\LogicException $le) {
    // class probably doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: I'm transferring from PHP5.2 and wants to use PHP 5.3 features where possible.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: Then you should definitely use Reflection API.

Comment: Why is that better than the PHP 5.3 feature?

Comment: @ultimatebuster: I think you misunderstood me. It is a "PHP5+" feature. AFAIR there is no major changes in reflection mechanism between PHP 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: `new $class` is not allowed in PHP 5.2. I think

Comment: -1. Convoluted, inefficient (using reflection), and unclear to whoever is reading the code, while the purpose `class_exists()` is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

first, you must test if $test class exists.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3 (or greater), you can catch exceptions thrown from [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

```
function __autoload($name) {
    // if class doesn't exist:
        throw new Exception("Class $name not found");
    // else, load class source
}


$test = 'SomeClass';    
try {
    $ins = new $test;
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```